# OpenCV : number of nested contours

Tags: opencv, contour

This is my first question here, thank you for reading it.

I am trying to count the number of inner contours inside a contour.

I found a nice tutorial showing how to use h_next and v_next

http://jmpelletier.com/a-simple-opencv-tutorial/

The problem is I use Mat and not IplImage.

I tried to convert it with:

Mat *oimg;
IplImage img = *oimg;

But I get an error when calling cvFindContours.

I also tried usign findContours which is built to work with Mat,

by going through the hierrarchy but it didnt work.

I'm usign C++ and OpenCV2.0

Thanks allot,

Tamir.

Comment: Use casting: mat matrix; iplimage* p; p = &((iplimage)matrix)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting the `cv::Mat` to an `IplImage` to use the C API, I suggest directly using the C++ version of `cvFindContours()`: `cv::findContours()`. Instead of building a true tree data structure, it is flattened and stored in two vectors:

```
cv::Mat image = // ...
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Check the [C++ API documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contours#findContours) for instructions on how to interpret `hierarchy` (emphasis mine):

> *hiararchy* – The optional output vector
>   that will contain information about
>   the image topology. It will have as
>   many elements as the number of
>   contours. For each contour contours[i]
>   , the elements hierarchy[i][0] ,
>   hiearchy[i](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contours#findContours) , hiearchy[i][2] ,
>   hiearchy[i][3] **will be set to 0-based
>   indices in contours of the next and
>   previous contours at the same
>   hierarchical level, the first child
>   contour and the parent contour,
>   respectively.** If for some contour i
>   there is no next, previous, parent or
>   nested contours, the corresponding
>   elements of hierarchy[i] will be
>   negative

Switching between the C and C++ API in the same codebase really hurts readability. I suggest only using the C API if the functionality you need is missing from the C++ API.